# For example, if coins = [1, 2, 5] and N = 11, return true if coins = [3, 77] and N = 100, return

Tags: objective-c

wait online。~

Given a number of coins with different denominations, e.g. [1, 2, 5] and test if they could be used to make up a certain amount (N), assuming you can use unlimited number of coins in each denomination.  For example, if coins = [1, 2, 5] and N = 11, return true if coins = [3, 77] and N = 100, return

Answer (score -1):

The idea is use a recursive function (here it will calculate with one first coin vs array of other coins then recursively reduce size of coin array ).

But sr I'm not familiar with Objective-C so I write one using C#. Use should convert it to Objective-C.

```
bool CanDo(int n, int [] arr)  
{
    if (arr.Length == 1)
    {
        if (n % arr[0] == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var ls = new List<int>(arr);
        ls.RemoveAt(0);
        int [] newarr = ls.ToArray();    //Create New array by deleting first element(current calculated element) of old array

        for(int i = 0; i <= n/arr[0]; i++)
        {
            int next_n = n - i * arr[0];
            if (next_n == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (next_n < 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(next_n > 0)
            {
                if( CanDo(next_n, newarr) )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is full code in C# that can print to console first found solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> resultString = new List<string>();
        static bool CanDo(int n, int [] arr)
        {
            if (arr.Length == 1)
            {
                if (n % arr[0] == 0)
                {
                    resultString.Add(n/ arr[0] + "*" + arr[0]);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var ls = new List<int>(arr);
                ls.RemoveAt(0);
                int [] newarr = ls.ToArray();    //Create New array by deleting first element of old array

                for(int i = 0; i <= n/arr[0]; i++)
                {
                    if (resultString.Count > 0)
                    {
                        resultString.RemoveAt(resultString.Count - 1);
                    }

                    int next_n = n - i * arr[0];
                    if (next_n == 0)
                    {
                        resultString.Add(i + "*" + arr[0]);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if (next_n < 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(next_n > 0)
                    {
                        if (i != 0)
                        {
                            resultString.Add(i + "*" + arr[0] + " + ");
                        }
                        if( CanDo(next_n, newarr) )
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                int[] arr = { 3, 5, 7 };
                int N = 20;
                resultString = new List<string>();

                if (CanDo(N, arr))
                {
                    resultString.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Can't do");
                    Console.Read();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exception
            }

        }
    }
}
```